# Outlook Mobile App email encryption (third-party crypto provider)

Tags: android, ios, email, encryption, outlook

I would like to implement a **smart card-based** *end-to-end* email encryption solution using **Outlook Mobile App** (*iOS, Android*).

Both the *sender* and the *receiver* would hold a **valid key pair/certificate** (hosted by their respective smart cards) issued by corporate ADCS.

The related "*key stores*" would be exposed through necessary OS components (*iOS Keychain, Android Keystore System*) **to the Outlook Mobile App**.

However, I am struggling finding **technical details** about how Outlook Mobile app *actually* performs email encryption/decryption.

**What would be the best way to connect the Outlook Mobile App to a third-party cryptography library for local (phone) email encryption ?**

Comment: I doubt that you can

Comment: Look for SMIME support (encoded CMS messages). If it's there, you may be in luck. If not, well, you're not.